# MySql Count with Join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables -

```
Users_tag (userID,tagID) 

tagId - userId
   1       1
   2       1
   3       2
   4       2
   5       4

Tags (id,tagText)

  id    tagText
  1      dog
  2      cat
  3      lion
  4      tiger
  5      chicken
```

I want my query to return tagId,TagText and count of each row based on userId.

Any help please...

Comment: why down vote? Question was legitimate and I got two answers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.id, a.tagText, COUNT(b.tagID) totalCount
FROM    Tags a
        LEFT JOIN users_tag b
            on a.ID = b.tagID
GROUP BY a.id, a.tagText
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68652/1)